# Unflattening data list into a nested list using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, list, automapper

I have a flatten data list (counties and cities) and I want to map into a unflatten (counties with cities) nested property list (State.County). Please check the following .NET 6.0 console application code:

```cs
using AutoMapper;

public class CountyAndCity
{
    public int CountyId { get; set; }
    public string CountyName { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public int CityPopulation { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Population { get; set; }
}

public class County
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<City> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class State
{
    public List<County> Counties { get; set; }
}

public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<CountyAndCity, City>()
            .ForMember(destination => destination.Id, options => options.MapFrom(source => source.CountyId))
            .ForMember(destination => destination.Name, options => options.MapFrom(source => source.CountyName))
            .ForMember(destination => destination.Population, options => options.MapFrom(source => source.CityPopulation));

        CreateMap<IEnumerable<CountyAndCity>, County>()
            .ForMember(destination => destination.Id, options => options.MapFrom(source => source.FirstOrDefault().CountyId))
            .ForMember(destination => destination.Name, options => options.MapFrom(source => source.FirstOrDefault().CountyName))
            .ForMember(destination => destination.Cities, options => options.MapFrom(source => source));

        CreateMap<IEnumerable<CountyAndCity>, State>()
            .ForMember(destination => destination.Counties, options => options.MapFrom(source => source));
    }
}

class HelloWorld
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var flattenData = new List<CountyAndCity>
        {
            new CountyAndCity { CountyId = 1, CountyName = "Albany", CityId = 10, CityName = "Cohoes", CityPopulation = 1000 },
            new CountyAndCity { CountyId = 1, CountyName = "Albany", CityId = 20, CityName = "Watervliet", CityPopulation = 1000 },
            new CountyAndCity { CountyId = 2, CountyName = "Bronx", CityId = 30, CityName = "Wakefield", CityPopulation = 2000 },
            new CountyAndCity { CountyId = 2, CountyName = "Bronx", CityId = 40, CityName = "Eastchester", CityPopulation = 2000 },
        };

        var unflattenData = new List<County>
        {
            new County { Id = 1, Name = "Albany", Cities = new List<City>
            {
                new City { Id = 10, Name = "Cohoes", Population = 1000 },
                new City { Id = 20, Name = "Watervliet", Population = 1000 },
            }},
            new County { Id = 2, Name = "Bronx", Cities = new List<City>
            {
                new City { Id = 30, Name = "Wakefield", Population = 2000 },
                new City { Id = 40, Name = "Eastchester", Population = 2000 },
            }},
        };

        var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(configuration => configuration.AddProfile(new AutoMapperProfile()));
        var mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
        State mappedData = mapper.Map<State>(flattenData);
        //Should be TRUE after some kind of custom comparison but it is goof enough for the example.
        bool result = mappedData.Counties == unflattenData;
    }
}
```

I'm receiving the following exception:

```cs
/*
Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
IEnumerable`1 -> State
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[CountyAndCity, ConsoleApp1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> State

Type Map configuration:
IEnumerable`1 -> State
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[CountyAndCity, ConsoleApp1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> State

Destination Member:
Counties
*/
```

What I'm doing wrong? What mappers should I create to transform the unflatten list into the flatten nested property: "Counties"?

Comment: Can you provide your automapper profile, for this kind of mapping you have to explicitly tell automapper what you mapping

Comment: You should try solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39438118/14202100

Comment: @Denis please check the profile: "AutoMapperProfile" included in the sample code. The solution you pointed don't answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may look for the [Custom Value Resolver](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html) to group data for `County`.

```cs
public class StateCountiesResolver : IValueResolver<List<CountyAndCity>, State, List<County>>
{
    public List<County> Resolve(List<CountyAndCity> src, State dest, List<County> destMember, ResolutionContext ctx)
    {
        destMember = src.GroupBy(x => x.CountyId)
            .Select(x => new County
            {
                Id = x.Key,
                Name = x.FirstOrDefault()?.CountyName,
                Cities = ctx.Mapper.Map<List<City>>(x.ToList())
            })
            .ToList();
        
        return destMember;
    }
}
```

```cs
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<CountyAndCity, City>()
            .ForMember(destination => destination.Id, options => options.MapFrom(source => source.CityId))
            .ForMember(destination => destination.Name, options => options.MapFrom(source => source.CityName))
            .ForMember(destination => destination.Population, options => options.MapFrom(source => source.CityPopulation));

        CreateMap<List<CountyAndCity>, State>()
            .ForMember(destination => destination.Counties, options => options.MapFrom<StateCountiesResolver>());
    }
}
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/alxLFI)

---

While with the below statement:

```cs
bool result = mappedData.Counties == unflattenData;
```

you will still get `false` when comparing both lists (even the contents of both lists are the same) as the references are used to compare instead of the *content* of both lists:

Instead, you need to override the `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` methods.

```cs
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Population { get; set; }
    
    
    public override bool Equals (Object obj)
    {
        if (obj is not City)
            return false;
        
        City b = (City)obj;
        
        return Id == b.Id
            && Name == b.Name
            && Population == b.Population;
    }
    
    
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Id.GetHashCode() ^ this.Name.GetHashCode() ^ this.Population.GetHashCode(); 
    }
}

public class County
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<City> Cities { get; set; }
    
    
    public override bool Equals (Object obj)
    {
        if (obj is not County)
            return false;
        
        County b = (County)obj;
        
        return Id == b.Id
            && Name == b.Name
            && Enumerable.SequenceEqual(Cities, b.Cities);
    }
    
    
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Id.GetHashCode() ^ this.Name.GetHashCode(); 
    }
}
```

And use `Enumerable.SequenceEqual()` method to compare the contents of the lists.

```cs
bool result = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(mappedData.Counties, unflattenData);
```